# BigQuery group by every possible combination

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table looking like this in BigQuery:

[image]

The first field is `id`, the second field is `url`. 
One line represents someone (an ID) who visited a URL. 
Let's say my URLs are `url1, url2, url3`. I would like to know how many unique IDs visited at least once the following tuples of URLs:

```
(url1)
(url2)
(url3)
(url1, url2)
(url1, url3)
(url2, url3)
(url1, url2, url3)
```

I'm not interested by URLs exactly, but the domain of the URL. 
For now, I have a solution but only for pairs of domains:

```
select
  NET.REG_DOMAIN(d1.url) as primary_url,
  NET.REG_DOMAIN(d2.url) as linked_url,
  count(distinct id) as shared_count
from `sample` d1
inner join `sample` d2 using(id)
where NET.REG_DOMAIN(d1.url) != NET.REG_DOMAIN(d2.url)
group by 1,2
```

With this I get what I want, but only for pairs of domains. 
For example, I don't get it for `(url1, url2, url3)` (assuming it's from different domains)

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if are you are not intrested in the URL and intrested only in the Domain.

Sol1:

```
select NET.REG_DOMAIN(url), count(distinct id) 
from inputtable
group by 1
```

if you want to count by domain but want all the URL's. It is not easily doable in traditional sql without keeping an upperlimit on number of elements(easily doable in spark look at collect_list in spark)

Sol2: (In SQL without spark)

```
 select domain
    , SUM(IF(rwn=1,url,NULL)) url1
    , SUM(IF(rwn=1,url2,NULL)) url2, ... 
    (select 
         NET.REG_DOMAIN(url) as domain, url, id,  
         row_number() over(partition by NET.REG_DOMAIN(url)) as rwn
    from inputtable) a
    group by domain
```

Above SQL, Basically gives the URL's as columns assocaited with a domain. Once you have all the columns, you can create a list/concat as a single column.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, could you explain how the first solution covers all cases I presented in the question please ?